# 404 status code for HTTP/2

Tags: https, 404, http, http-headers

How does a correct 404 status code look like on using HTTP/2 protocol? `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` seems to be for the previous protocol version, but I can't find anywhere something meaningful about status *update*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/2 will still use the `404 Not Found` status, as well as all the other status codes defined by HTTP/1.1.

https://nestify.io/blog/http2-must-know/ says:

> The semantics of [HTTP] will not be affected by this new version, that is, HTTP headers, values and usage formats will be kept. Significant improvements are in information transport performance in addition to lower latency and higher throughput.